# ffmpeg audio watermark at specific time

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a way to add an audio watermark, on specific time, to a video file (with existing audio) .
 something like: `ffmpeg -i mainAVfile.mov -i audioWM.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a] amix=inputs=2:enable='between(t,9,10)' [aud]; [0:v][aud]" -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1280:720:sws_dither=ed:flags=lanczos, setdar=16:9" -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 48000 -af "aformat=channel_layouts=stereo, aresample=async=1000" -threads 0 -y output.mp4`

The above command gives me this error `Timeline ('enable' option) not supported with filter 'amix'`. `amerge` didn't work as well. I kind of get lost with filter_complex syntax, specifically with the following conditions

- On the main AV file, both audio and video tracks are filtered
- Watermark should be between the 9th and 10th second (I already
  generated a 1 second, 10k tone file)
- The watermark need to survive the proceeding audio transcode

Comment: Not all filters support the `enable` option. See the output of `ffmpeg -filters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i mainAVfile.mov -i audioWM.wav
  -filter_complex 
      "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=stereo,aresample=async=1000[main];
       [1:a]atrim=0:1,adelay=9000|9000[wm];[main][wm]amix=inputs=2"
  -vf "scale=1280:720:sws_dither=ed:flags=lanczos,setdar=16:9" -c:v libx264    
  -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 96k
  -threads 0 -y output.mp4
```

It's preferable to perform all filtering in a single filtergraph. But I've kept the video filter as-is.

Comment: Your code works! I just had to change `trim` to `atrim`.

Comment: It looks like the audioWM.wav file starts at the beginning of mainAVfile.mov and not on the 9th second. I tried changing values but it doesn't seem to effect anything.

Comment: Switched to a different filter; looks like a regression with asetpts.

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible for `adelay` to be represented by percentage of duration of the source video? Assuming I get the duration value, is it possible to have something like `adelay=10%/$duration`?

Comment: No. FFmpeg does not expose duration of inputs to filters or encoders.